# How to display array firestore with space between items

Tags: javascript, arrays, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to do a recipe app, and I want to show the ingredients that are storage in a Firestore database, but when I use `{{ recipe.ingredients }}`, the items are displayed without space between the items, and I need it with space, how can I do this?

I know that with javascript I can use .join(" ,"), but I can't figure out how to do this in ionic

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let recipe of recipes">
   <div>{{ recipe.ingredientes }}</div>
</ion-card>
```

It's like "onion,egg,meat" and I want "onion, egg, meat"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all the ingredients as an array from the recipes array.

In component.ts file:

```
this.ingredientes = recipes.map((recipe) => (recipe.ingredientes));
this.ingredientesString = ingredientes.join(', ');
```

In html file, display the string inside the ionic card:

```
<ion-card>
   <div>{{ ingredientesString }}</div>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `recipe.ingredientes` is an array, then you should be able to use:

```
recipe.ingredientes.join(", ")
```